# Git removed/removing an already merged file without a delete commit

Tags: git, merge

I'm trying to figure out how this situation is occurring, a bit of a mystery, related to a file that has disappeared without a corresponding delete commit.

The file was created in a branch and then merged into master, and now somehow is not present in master. When I run:

```
git checkout master
git merge my_branch
```

It shows 'up to date'.

When I run, from master:

```
git log --all --/path/to/file
```

it shows *only* the initial commit where the file is first created, but it is not actually present in the directory. However, if I checkout the branch itself, the file is there.

So, the file has disappeared from master somehow, sometime, but there is seemingly no associated delete commit.

It seems like this should not be possible. Any ideas or suggestions on how to investigate this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: could you add the `--follow` flag to the `git log` command you're using and share the results with us?

Comment: it might get renamed. in that case, log indeed will only show your initial commit, because renaming is just delete + add.

Comment: Does using the pickaxe help? http://www.philandstuff.com/2014/02/09/git-pickaxe.html

Comment: @Mureinik Well, it shows the same single (initial) commit that is shown without --follow, but then it also shows commits that are not related to that specific file.

Comment: I am confused by your description. `git log` normally shows commits in priority queue order, which (while a bit complicated) generally turns into reverse chronological order. But then you say "shows the ... (initial) commit ... followed by other commits". The initial commit should come *last*, in reverse chronological order. However, that aside, if `--follow` shows other commits, that does mean Git believes the file was renamed along the way.

Comment: Yes, I'm confused as well @torek. The other commits when I run --follow seem entirely unrelated to the file in question.

Comment: Did the merge have conflicts?  Or, was it created with `--no-commit`?  If the merge commit itself is responsible for the file's removal, log output can be confusing.  With the merge checked out, you can quickly check for this with `git diff HEAD HEAD^` and `git diff HEAD HEAD^2`

Comment: @Jonathan.Brink thank you for the pointer, that actually seems very useful and valuable. It does show the specific commit that introduced/created the file, but only that commit, unfortunately.

Comment: Note that you can add `--name-status` to your `git log` commands to get them to show how the file was affected. This will ignore merges unless you add `-m` since `git log` normally ignores merge diffs entirely (`-m` effectively splits each merge into two or more non-merge virtual commits, one for each parent, enabling things like `--name-status` to work).

Comment: @torek, thank you, that seems to provide a clue! When I run log with --name-status --follow -m --file (I'm still not sure why --follow shows lots of commits unrelated to the file) it does show the deletes, finally. :) Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's still a lot of interesting side items in the comments, but I suspect your:

```
git log --all -- path/to/file
```

is getting trimmed down by [History Simplification](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html#_history_simplification).

You can avoid this in one of two ways: either add `--full-history`, which simply disables history simplification entirely, or add `-m`, which splits merges (so that there is nothing to simplify).  I have not tested the `-m` method.

Comment: Thank you, @torek, this does seem to show more of a full history (and also , but I'm also not sure why it shows commits related to other files beyond just the file that I indicate after the --/path/to/file. It doesn't seem to allow the --name-status along with the --full-history switch.

Comment: You *should* be able to combine those (and even `--follow` as well, but note that `--follow` is a horrible hack that often misses some cases): `git log --name-status --full-history --all -- path/to/file`, for instance.

Comment: It does not seem to be allowing that combination, particularly with --name-status, which was the extremely useful flag that showed where the file was actually being deleted in the other commits. Regardless, this was unbelievably helpful, thank you, @torek!

Comment: It works for me (note that you still need `-m` to split merges to get anything useful from merge commits) when I run it on the Git repository for Git, for instance. (This is pretty merge-heavy so `git log --all --name-status --full-history -- builtin/apply.c` shows few commits that touch the file, but with `-m` each merge touches the file.)